# setCell updates wrong cell

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm trying to define a small table (HTML table) within a cell, by using a formatter that returns the HTML code. The content is based on some hidden fields in the same record.

The initial setup of the tables within the cell is going well. The problem is that later I plan to use "setCell", modify the hidden fields, and see the affect on the field with the table structure.

What happens is that jqGrid approaches the WRONG cell and creates some mess in it. I've created a jsFiddle to demonstrate it.

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div>
<input id="update" type="button" value="Update">
</div>

var mydata = [{
    id: 1,
  hiddenA: 1,
  hiddenB: 2,
  hiddenC: 4,
  hiddenD: 8,
  hiddenE: 16,
  hiddenF: 32,
  hiddenG: 64,
  hiddenH: 128
}];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
  datatype: "local",
  data: mydata,
  height: 250,
  colNames: [
    'id',
    'hiddenA', 
    'hiddenB', 
    'hiddenC', 
    'hiddenD', 
    'hiddenE', 
    'hiddenF', 
    'hiddenG', 
    'hiddenH', 
    'visibleA', 
    'visibleB'
  ],
  colModel: [
    {name: 'id', hidden: true, key: true},
    {name: 'hiddenA', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenB', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenC', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenD', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenE', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenF', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenG', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'hiddenH', hidden: true, width: 50},
    {name: 'visibleA', width: 80, formatter: addFormatter},
    {name: 'visibleB', width: 80, formatter: subFormatter}
  ],
  caption: "Table within a cell",
  gridview: true,
  loadonce: true,
  viewrecords: true,
  loadui: "disable",
});

function addFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
  var ret = " \
    <table class='details-table'> \
    <tr><td>A+B:</td><td class='al-right'>{0}</td></tr> \
    <tr><td>B+C:</td><td class='al-right'>{1}</td></tr> \
    <tr><td>C+D:</td><td class='al-right'>{2}</td></tr> \
    <tr><td>D+A:</td><td class='al-right'>{3}</td></tr> \
    </table> \
    ";
  ret = ret.replace("{0}", rowObject.hiddenA + rowObject.hiddenB);
  ret = ret.replace("{1}", rowObject.hiddenB + rowObject.hiddenC);
  ret = ret.replace("{2}", rowObject.hiddenC + rowObject.hiddenD);
  ret = ret.replace("{3}", rowObject.hiddenD + rowObject.hiddenA);

  return (ret);
}

function subFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
  var ret = " \
    <table class='details-table'> \
    <tr><td>E-F:</td><td class='al-right'>{0}</td></tr> \
    <tr><td>F-G:</td><td class='al-right'>{1}</td></tr> \
    <tr><td>G-H:</td><td class='al-right'>{2}</td></tr> \
    <tr><td>H-A:</td><td class='al-right'>{3}</td></tr> \
    </table> \
  ";
  ret = ret.replace("{0}", rowObject.hiddenE - rowObject.hiddenF);
  ret = ret.replace("{1}", rowObject.hiddenF - rowObject.hiddenG);
  ret = ret.replace("{2}", rowObject.hiddenG - rowObject.hiddenH);
  ret = ret.replace("{3}", rowObject.hiddenH - rowObject.hiddenE);

  return (ret);
}

$( "#update" ).bind( "click", function() {
    $("#grid").jqGrid("setCell", 1, "hiddenE", 256);
  $("#grid").jqGrid("setCell", 1, "visibleB", "1");
});
```

[jFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/unle70/p9nk0km7/6/)

As you can see, the "Update" button is changing "hiddenE" field and then touching the "visibleB" field, just to cause an update. But what happens in actual is that "visibleA" field is modified and destroyed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in version 4.6 you use. The problem is in setCell method in case of table cells inside the cell you want to update.

The same problem persist in Guriddo jqGrid which we support. We have fixed the problem in GitHub and in case you want to use Guriddo jqGrid product you can test it.

We know that in some cases it is not possible to upgrade to the other jqGrid clone products and that is the reason that we never say - do not use this "old" jqGrid product.

In case if you are little familiar with javascript you can fix the 4.6 jqGrid code and use it - for this purpose you will need to open the jquery.jqGrid.js file (not the minified) and find setCell method this is around line 3646. Find the expression

```
var tcell = $("td:eq("+pos+")",ind);
```

and replace it with

```
var tcell = ind.cells[pos];
```

Then you can minify this file and use it.

In case if you do not want to do this you can upgrade to one of the supported jqGrid clones - free jqGrid or the commercial Guriddo jqGrid

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have version 5.2.1 installed. I found the relevant line and it is actually: " var tcell = $("td:eq("+pos+")",ind), cl=0, rawdat=[]; " in my version.  I guess the issue is not fully resolved yet.

Comment: After trying your suggested modification, indeed the correct cell is being updated. But another problem is that the "rowobject" parameter into the Formatter is behaving different than the first time (row creation). In the first call it's a nice object with fields. Following the "setCell" it's just a list that holds the HTML information without any fields. Any reason for that?

Comment: You need to know that when defining a custom formatter function like in your code, you will need to define your own custom unformat function to get back to original data, since the grid does not know your content defined from the formatter. I recommend you to read the [Guriddo Documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#custom-formatter).  Additionally you will need to know that there is a small problem in the current setCell code about this. The fix will be published tomorrow and I will let you know how to download it.

Comment: I have fix the code [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/364d028f2574bc6b1d5131f2cd22ef81baad89aa) You can get the update from [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) and test it. Note that if the datatype is local it is not needed to write a unformat function - in all other cases you will need todefine a unformat function.